# Get size of each logical partition in Cosmos DB collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there any way or metrics that can use on azure portal, to get the list of all logical partitions with their assigned and available size details.
I can see only couple of partitions out of 100 logical partitions in Storage section available in metrics.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question,azure portal metrics only shows the top few partitions in a collection.

I found [Collection Partition - List Usages REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db-resource-provider/collectionpartition/listusages) which may meet your requirements.

You could view some metrics based on the `PartitionUsage` object

[image]